# Using vega-lite and vega3 in Google Colaboratory

Tags: vega-lite, google-colaboratory

I follow the instruction to install the module [here](https://github.com/vega/ipyvega/tree/vega3).

It seems to install fine. No errors.

But when I follow the [example notebook](https://github.com/vega/ipyvega/blob/vega3/notebooks/VegaLite.ipynb). Nothing is displayed.

Can vega-lite be use with Colab? Or did I make a mistake somewhere?

Update:
Thanks to blois, I create an example of interactive visualization in only a few lines. See this [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=14-adD9vO8GjkNo_cTT7dl27m8QYtuhYX).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vega requires the same initialization that Altair uses, see the Altair example in the charts sample notebook:
https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=/v2/external/notebooks/charts.ipynb&scrollTo=beTgCbVa_wFA

A complete repro of the example notebook:
https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=1UHVm-vm5VXgOmT10t0eIYDa8_XPkvqui

Comment: Thank you so much. See [my example](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=14-adD9vO8GjkNo_cTT7dl27m8QYtuhYX) here. Isn't it cool?